# HDMI + USB communications

Tags: usb, hdmi

I have a LG-P930 cellphone with Gingerbread 2.3.5. This device has a micro-USB connector that shares pinout with HDMI. I bought a MHL adapter but it seems that the USB plug on this device is for power only.

I know that my question is not purely about Android but does someone know about a MHL adapter that would preserve the USB data connection? In other words, I would like to connect to my HDMI screen ***while*** communicating with the computer through USB.

Comment: Have you tried an usb hub? I have a microUSB->female-USB converter here, which I then connect to a hub, and I can connect a keyboard, mouse and sdcard reader at the same time without any trouble. Perhaps it works the same with HDMI/MHL, I'm not sure (that's actually what I'm searching this site for, so I'm curious as to whether this worked!).

Answer (score 2):

USB and MHL share the same pins on the connector. Once the phone is in MHL mode, there is no USB capability. So, currently you can't use MHL and USB simultaneously.